# UPDATE one to one relationship EntityState.Modified .net

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a simple model Config and MyValue:

```
public Class Config
   Public Property ConfigId as Integer
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property MyValue as MyValue
   Public Property ...
end class

Public Class MyValue
   Public Property MyValueId as Integer
   Public Property Value as Decimal
   Public Property Info As String
   Public Property ...
end class
```

I want to update my Config in database after changing:
- Name Text in TextBox (binding ViewModel)
- MyValue object in ComboBox (binding ViewModel)
- other values with binding

```
Public Function SaveExececute() As String
   ObjConfig.Name = SomeString    'FAKE All is binded'
   ObjConfig.MyValue = SomeObject 'FAKE All is binded'
   ' ... '

Using ctx As New DbContext
     Try
        ctx.Entry(ObjConfig.MyValue).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
        ctx.Entry(ObjConfig).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
        ctx.SaveChanges()
        Return "UPDATED"
     Catch ex As Exception
         Return ex.Message
     End Try
End Using
End Sub
```

[IMAGE DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTGjk.png)

all the values as been modified on database except my new MyValue with Id 2 (MyValue_MyValueId = 1 on my sql database), the Disconnect Method do not recognize the new object MyValue, how to Attach and update the new Object MyValue ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in Vb.Net, so i will try (i use C#)

Your `ObjConfig.MyValue` and your `ObjConfig` aren't in the same context of your `ctx` because you open then in different contexts

to fix it you should procede as following:

```
Using ctx As New DbContext
     Try

        Dim ObjConfig as New ObjConfig() = ctx.ObjConfigEntity.Find(ObjConfig.Id) ''Or seach by you data
        Dim MyValue as  New MyValue() = ctx.MyValueEntity.Find(ObjConfig.MyValue.Id)

        ctx.Entry(MyValue).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
        ctx.Entry(ObjConfig).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified

        ctx.SaveChanges()

        Return "UPDATED"
     Catch ex As Exception
         Return ex.Message
     End Try
End Using
```

In summary you can not use data that was loaded out of `using` to update your open context within`using`, because they are different

Comment: in fact the 2 lines :

Comment: Thanks but not working, in fact the 2 first  lines are fake on execute Method, the model is entirely binded with the xaml, the "ObjConfig.MyValue" is an SelectedItem. With break debug my Object contains all the new values, just the property MyValue doesn't change. (edit with Image, for visualize)